# Are the data stored with the tempstore.private and tempstore.shared services expected to be removed when the user account is deleted?

Tags: users

Both the tempstore.private and tempstore.shared services store data which have an associated owner; for logged-in users, that is the user ID.

When an account is deleted, are the data having that user ID as owner removed?

I looked at [`User::postDelete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3ApostDelete/8.6.x), but there isn't code for that.

```
public static function postDelete(EntityStorageInterface $storage, array $entities) {
  parent::postDelete($storage, $entities);
  $uids = array_keys($entities);
  \Drupal::service('user.data')
    ->delete(NULL, $uids);
}
```

It could be I didn't look at the correct class, or the code to delete those data is still missing from Drupal core.

Should I expect the data stored with the tempstore.private and tempstore.shared services be immediately deleted after a user account is deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user's temp storage deletion isn't attached to the user deletion process.

If you look at the class, [`PrivateTempStoreFactory`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TempStore%21PrivateTempStoreFactory.php/class/PrivateTempStoreFactory/8.5.x), instantiated for `tempstore.private` & `tempstore.shared`, you can see that the class has an `expire` property that determines the storage's TTL (in seconds).

These services are instantiated with an `expire` value of defined by `parameters:tempstore.expire` in [`core.services.yml`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/8.5.x), with a default of 604800 seconds (1 week), so the temp storage will expire 1 week after its creation.